# text-overflow elipsis not working?

Tags: css

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/vxghC/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="study-box folder-box">
    <div class="folder-box-title">
        <div> TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
.folder-box-title > div {
margin-left: 10px;
margin-bottom: 7px;
-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.study-box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 2px;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` to your `.folder-box-title`, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/cWDtM/

More here: http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html

> text-overflow comes into play only when:
>
> 1. the box has overflow other than visible (with overflow: visible the
>      text simply flows out of the box)
> 2. the box has white-space: nowrap or
>      a similar method of constraining the way the text is laid out.
>      (Without this, the text would wrap to the next line)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a `width` for the div containing the text, and also don't let the text `overflow` the container.

```
width:150px;
overflow:hidden;
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/vxghC/6/